# SQL - Lead function to get dates from next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a date and value for example:

```
    AccID    Date          Value
    1      01/01/2007      10
    1      01/02/2008      20
    1      01/03/2009      40
```

I want to create a new table that starts from the date in row 1 and ends with the date in row 2 and so on.....for example

```
    AccID    Date           DateEnd           Value
      1      01/01/2007     01/02/2008          10
      1      01/02/2008     01/03/2009          20
      1      01/03/2009     01/04/2050          40


  Select
       date,
       isnull(lead(date) over (partition by accID order by date), '01/04/2050') as DateEnd,
       value
  from column A
```

I have tried this code but I can't seem to get the correct output. This is the output I am currently getting

```
     AccID    Date           DateEnd           Value
      1      01/02/2008     01/02/2009          20
      1      01/02/2009     01/03/2007          40
      1      01/01/2007     01/04/2050          10
```

Comment: And what does *can't seem to get it working* actually mean? Is your code above verbatim, ie your date value is unquoted? That's an error right there.

Comment: I am not getting the correct output as per the post

Comment: Why are you making it so hard for us to help you? We can't see your screen

Comment: Still have no idea what your problem is. Side note, `lead()` allows you to provide a default value you don't need `isnull`

Comment: I'll have a wild guess; your dates are not dates at all, but (n)varchar. So the ordering is on strings not dates.

Comment: Also is your table really named `column`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any output, you are getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'partition'.

You get the correct results when you correct the error

```
 Select
       date,
       isnull(lead(date) over (partition by accID order by date), '01/04/2050') as DateEnd,
       value
  from column A
```

Edit: Do yourself some favours and apply the following:

- Avoid the use of reserved words or if you "must" use them, surround the column or table name with [ ] e.g. [date], [value],[column]
- Research the function you're going to use to make the most of what it has to offer, to simplify your queries e.g. [See the documentaion for Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Use date formats that are unambiguous e.g. '2050-04-01' in preference to '01/04/2050'. The latter could be either 1st April or 4th January depending on where in the world you happen to be